# PEAR_Installer_Role_Pear_Installer_role_doc error

Tags: php, pecl, pear

I try to install imagick in mint 9 (lxde) and there is error

```
nerkn@nerkn-laptop ~/siil $ sudo pecl install imagick
downloading imagick-3.0.1.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.0.1.tgz (93,920 bytes)
.....................done: 93,920 bytes
ERROR: Unknown Role class: "PEAR_Installer_Role_Pear_Installer_role_doc"
```

Can any one help?

```
$ dpkg -l php5*
ii  php5-cli                                             5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9 
ii  php5-common                                          5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9                                     
ii  php5-curl                                            5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9                                     
un  php5-dev                                             <none>                                               
ii  php5-gd                                              5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9                                     
ii  php5-imagick                                         2.1.1RC1-1build3                                     
un  php5-json                                            <none>                                               
ii  php5-memcache                                        3.0.4-2build1                                        
un  php5-mhash                                           <none>                                               
ii  php5-mysql                                           5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9                                     
un  php5-mysqli                                          <none>                                               
ii  php5-sqlite                                          5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9                                     
un  php5-suhosin                                         <none>                                               
ii  php5-xdebug                                          2.0.5-1ubuntu1

$  mount | grep /dev/sda5
/dev/sda5 on / type ext3 (rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro)
```

Comment: question is still valid. ı just continue using exec & convert. Not native php libs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your PEAR installation:

```
$ pear upgrade pear
```

(The `pecl` command is part of PEAR)

Chances stand that your current pecl/pear setup is broken and needs to be fixed first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to add these lines after the first line (which is #!/bin/sh) of "/usr/bin/pear":

```
# sudo vim /usr/bin/pear

#!/bin/sh
export LC_ALL="C"
export LANG="C"
```

Or you can do this manually at every bash session before you run `pear` or `pecl`.

Comment: You should ***NOT*** be modifying the `pear` script -- your changes will be stomped on by the next PHP upgrade.  If you want to set these environment variables permanently do so in *the proper place* (your `.profile` or shell's `rc` file).

Comment: @voretaq7 Yep you're completely right, my bad. It was just a sloppy answer to quick fix, sorry

Comment: dursunturan right, this problem caused by php Turkish locale. (I=ı and İ=i in turkish). Forcing locales fixes problem.